# Returning HTML Ends Loop Premature

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, innerhtml

I am using javascript to validate some form elements. The fields I want to be required are passed into my validateReqFields function when the form is submitted. Everything is working perfectly until I get to the for loop that is meant to add an error message the an empty  beside the form field. It seems that as soon as one field fails and it adds the message to the div, the for loop does not continue.

The HTML Form Elements:

```
First Name <input type="text" name="firstName"  onkeypress="return checkField(event, letters);"/><div id="firstNameMsg" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
<br>
Last Name <input type="text"  name="lastName" onkeypress="return checkField(event,        letters);"/><div id="lastNameMsg" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
```

The Javascript function:

```
function validateReqFields(formName, reqFields){
var fieldArray = reqFields.split(",");
var failedList = new Array();
var message = "Required Field";

for(var i=0; i<fieldArray.length; i++){
    removeWhiteSpace(fieldArray[i]);
    var s = eval('document.'+formName+'.'+fieldArray[i]+'.value');
    if(s.length<1) { failedList.push(fieldArray[i]); }
}

if(failedList.length >= 1) { 

    for(var i=0; i<failedList.length; i++) {
        //BUG - Only shows first failed field.
        document.getElementById(failedList[i] + 'Msg').innerHTML = message;
    }

} else {
    document.mForm.submit();
}
}

function removeWhiteSpace(mString){
mString = mString.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,' ');
return mString;
}
```

I have done a few tests and concluded that when the for loops sets the innerHtml on the first div element, it breaks the for loop. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'd guess because you've altered the DOM at the location your scanning through.  Just curious but why not use jQuery and make your life a lot easier?

Comment: Javascript is new to me and i'd prefer to learn the nuts and bolts before simplifying things with jQuery.

Comment: You can avoid abusing eval if you use the [] property access notation: `document[formName][fieldArray[i]].value`

Comment: Using eval seems to be the only way to call form elements without prematurely ending my for loop. I've also come to the conclusion that calling document.getElementById('elementID') also causes the loop to only run once.

Comment: Are you testing on FF, Chome, IE? Some browsers hide javascript errors from the users(IE don't do it), if your code is throwing some error the loop(and everything after) will be aborted. If you are using FF try FireBug, for Chrome just hit F12.

Comment: Using FF, and Firebug does not seem to be catching any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My removeWhiteSpace function was not working correctly, thus everything after my first field was failing. Silly mistake. Please close this question.